# Finding Intersection Points between 3rd Order ODE and a line?

Tags: matlab, intersection, points, ode

How can I find the intersection points between the solution of a 3rd order ODE and a line y=x?

My ODE's code is

```
sol=dsolve('D3y-4*D2y+Dy+2*y=0,y(0)=-4,Dy(0)=-6,D2y(0)=-4')
x=0:2
y=subs(sol,'t',x)
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the numerical values of the intersections:

Create an anonymous function that is zero at the intersections between your solution and the line you seek:

```
sol = dsolve('D3y-4*D2y+Dy+2*y=0,y(0)=-4,Dy(0)=-6,D2y(0)=-4');
my_func = @(x) subs(sol,'t',x) - x; % Your solution - x is equal to zero at the %intersections
```

then, if you want to find the values graphically:

```
plot(-5:.01:5,my_func(-5:.01:5))
```

or numerically, by optimization routine:

```
x = fzero(my_func,0); % I find x = -.6847
```

which will look for a zero of the function near to 0.  It will not find all the zeros so you will need to start the fzero function near values where you expect the intersections to be.

Hope this helps,

Andrew

Edits:  a how to of the bisection method.

Once we have our anonymous one dimensional function "my_func" if you don't want to use an optimization method to solve the equation, but happen to know a range [range_{min} range_{max}]in which my_func = 0 then the following algorithm will find the zero of the function for you, provided you're working with a continuous function:

```
range_min = 0; % say our range is [0 2]
range_max = 2;

error_tolerance = .0001; % will find the answer to within .0001

while (range_max - range_min < error_tolerance)
range_temp = (range_max + range_min)/2;
if ((my_func(range_temp) <0 & my_func(range_max)>0) | (my_func(range_temp) >0 & my_func(range_max)<0))
range_min = range_temp;

else if ((my_func(range_min)<0 & my_func(range_temp)>0) | (my_func(range_min)>0 & my_func(range_temp)<0))
    range_max = range_temp;

else if (my_func(range_temp == 0)
range_min = range_temp;
range_max = range_temp;

    end

end

t_intersection = (range_min + range_max)/2;
```

So some explanation: if the function is continuous, and yours is, then if it intersects y=t at t_intersection then at our modified function my_func(t) = sol(t)-t will have a zero at t_intersection.  Since my_func is continuous then we can find a zero of the function provided we know two values of the function, one that is greater than zero and one that is less than zero.

So we start with these known points and define a range [range_min range_max] where either my_func(range_min)<0 and my_func(range_max)>0 or vise-versa.  Then we cut this range in half, by creating the midpoint range_temp = mean(range_min and _max).  We now create a new range [range_temp range_max] or [range_min range_temp] so that we preserve a sign change of my_func over the range.  We repeat this process until we reach a satisfactory accuracy.

One caveat though, this will only find one zero within the initial range you provide.  That is a fundamental frustration with most zero finding methods, and more generally the field of optimization of which zero finding can be considered a special case.

- If you need more on the bisection method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method
- If you need more on zero finding methods, I would look in a university library for a book on numerical analysis.
- If you need more on anonymous functions in Matlab (the " = @(t)" thing I was using), then check here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html

I think that covers it, good luck.

--Andrew

Comment: Erm... okay... somehow I don't get it... I mean - I never find how much X is. Erm. How should it be for a simple function like t = 0:.3:10;
y = sin(t);

Comment: Okay... Erm... Well what you've written finds only one intersection point, but it's out of the interval [0 2] and it obviously doesn't find the other intersection point that will be somewhere around x=1, y=0.

Comment: @lzumi, comment 1: If you wanted to find the intersections of y=t and y=sin(t) you would look for the zeros of the function z(t) = sin(t) - t.  You would create an anonymous function in matlab by: z = @(t) sin(t) - t; then find t_zero = fzero(z,0);

Comment: @lzumi, comment 2: It's hard to explain how to find zeros of a function, which is equivalent to finding intersections of functions, in the general case.  I've added some edits on the bisection method to get you started.

Comment: Okay... Thanks... I added 'x2 = fzero(my_func,1);' and it finds it as 1.6516 and on the graphic it's more than obvious that the intersection should be at 1.1ish

Comment: @lzumi When defining my_func, did you remember to subtract -x.  The offset could be due to that.  I know of some reasons why fzero fails to find an answer, but they're not that common.  Try running the bisection method code I wrote.  Remember that you need a value for your initial ranges that provide my_func with a positive and negative value.  I'm off to bed now, good luck!

Comment: I tried running the bisection method and it gives me an answer 1. As for the fzero I've substracted x  from my func. I think the problem is that fzero finds the intersection point of my_func with y=x because when I plotted the graphics of my_func it was a slightly curved one that intersects x at around 1.6

Comment: @lzumi Be careful about plotting y = my_func(x) against y = x.  Remember that your solution intersects y=x when my_func(x) = 0, not when my_func intersects with y=x.  If you want to plot your solution you should create another anon. function: my_sol = @(x) subs(sol,'t',x).  This can be plotted against y = x.  The intersection of my_sol and y = x should be at (1,1) as found by running the bisection algorithm on my_func.  Also, when you post a comment, try to add "@sevenless" so I get a notification.

Comment: @sevenless I'm trying to be careful... Okay... I'm trying now a different function: sol=dsolve('D3y-10*D2y+8*Dy+y=24,y(0)=1,Dy(0)=2,D2y(0)=8') where  x =-3:1; The fzero finds it as a -1.2318 but the bisection finds it as -1. Which one is the correct? And which one should I use? :s

Comment: @lzumi check it this way: func = @(x) subs(sol,'t',x); Then check: func(-1.2318), is it equal to -1.2318?  Also, check func(-1), is it equal to -1?  Basically if func(x) = x then an intersection occurs at x.

Comment: @sevenless - it's -1.2318, when I try it with -1 it returns -0.7184. :) Then I suppose I should just leave the fzero, right? :)

Comment: @lzumi I suppose so.  If one of the methods is giving you the right answer, then go with it.  I'll play around with the bisection method and try to figure out why it's not returning the same value as fzero.

Comment: @sevenless  Thank you. For the help, let me know if you find the mistake in the bitsection (if there's one) - but the most obvious thing is that it returns range_min + range_max / 2 (in the case above -3+1 / 2 = -1. It was the same with the other example as well 0+2/2 = 1